# Black screen even from motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I have a problem, the computer was running fine for at least a year, so it's a sudden thing, nothing was changed or removed or added.

Today when I turned on the computer it showed a blank screen, no starting up, so I thought maybe something is wrong between the video card and the monitor.
The monitor and cable work fine, tested it on another computer.
I moved the cable to go from the motherboard instead of the video card, but still the same problem.

Reading another post, I tried removing both RAM chips, when turned on, it beeped 3 times, interrupted and repeats, no other change. Tried to put 1 of the 2 RAM chips back, still blank screen.

Is the motherboard fried?

The CPU ventilator is spinning, the keyboard does **NOT** show lights such as caps lock.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix.

I read from another post to remove the RAM chips, clean them and exchange them in places (in which slot they were), now the monitor is showing.